# Watir how to change locators from ":class" to another locator to automate this proccess

Tags: ruby, watir, rubymine

basically in instagram when ur trying to unfollow a person theres first a following button once u press that another window opens on instagram browsers saying "unfollow" or "cancel" the tag_name doesnt work for this locator only the class and the class changes over time so this wouldnt be automated is there any way to make this program automated?

```
    ap "Starting un-following procedure on user: #{val}"   

    browser.button(:tag_name  =>'Following'.split).exists?
    browser.button(:tag_name =>'Following'.split).click

    ap "Waiting 5 Seconds"
    sleep(5)

    ap "Unfollowing user: #{val}"
    browser.button(:class  =>'aOOlW -Cab_   '.split).click
```

"browser.button(:tag_name =>'Unfollow'.split).click" will also not work it totally doesn't find this locator at all on the page but the others work.

after awhile the "browser.button(:class  =>'aOOlW -Cab_   '.split).click" will change and outputs a error cause it cannot find this on the page cause the class will change over time as u change the website to other users within instagram.

Crashes because it cannot find the locator that was inputted " browser.button(:class  =>'aOOlW -Cab_   '.split).click" after working for 15 pages then the class "aOOlW -Cab_   " changes to another value and the automation process is failed.

Comment: Can you please edit the output. It is hard to read that error stack

Comment: `browser.button(:tag_name =>'Unfollow'.split).click` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @supputuri no that hasnt worked i also added that in that wont be able to be found at the page at all not even once

Comment: @StevenAguilar edited it now

Comment: `tag_name` is for the type of element (e.g. `div`, `span`, `a`), it is not the locator you want for what you are doing.

Comment: "changes to another value" - what value does it change to? A previous edit referenced a Net ReadTimeout error, which is not the error you would get when the element can not be located.